# How to close file of FileHandler opened in Python process

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm using a logger inside Python process (multiprocessing.process) to log. I declare a FileHandler to log to disk, once the job is done I try to close the underlying file but can't achieve that. My real problem is that I spawn a lot of process resulting in `IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files`

I reproduce the error with this snippet (test_process.py):

```
import logging
import multiprocessing

class TestProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('test')
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.handler = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
        self.handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        self.handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.handler)

    def run(self):
        self.logger.info('hello')
        self.logger.removeHandler(self.handler)
        self.handler.close()
```

and when I run this:

```
from test_process import TestProcess
p=TestProcess()
p.start()
p.join()
```

You can check that there is file descriptor alive for the file test.log.

Any hint to overcome this behaviour?

Comment: Interesting case, and very nice to provide the way to reproduce it! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue adding the following to the class:

```
def __del__(self):
    self.logger.removeHandler(self.handler)
    self.handler.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because multiprocess uses forks, so anything in `__init__` is run in the parent process, including your log file creation.

When you call `start`, the process forks and the file handle is shared between the two processes.

You should setup your logging in the `run` function. Then you don't have to worry about that.